# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as $2 \times 2$ block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I have demonstrated that the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
x & -y \\
y & x
\end{pmatrix}$$
builds a ring that is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ under the map
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
x & -y \\
y & x
\end{pmatrix} \to x +iy$$
However now I have to show that every automorphism of $\mathbb{C}^n$ can be represented as a matrix with commutative $2 \times 2$ blocks by using the above mentioned isomorphism. The only intuition that I have is that I could maybe build a matrix that has on the diagonal blocks that look like the one above.

I don't really get how I can properly represent $\mathbb C^n$ as a $2n \times 2n$ matrix.

Comment: ''The only intuition that I have is that I could maybe build a matrix that has on the diagonal blocks that look like the one above.'' $${}$$ Looks pretty good to me. Have you tried to elaborate on this train of thought?

Comment: Well yes and it appears to be consistent, but how do I go about proving that every automorphism can be represented by this kind matrix? And how would the coefficients of this matrix look like: for example, how would the matrix that represents a map where every coordinate of x is doubled look?

Comment: Wait, what exactly is automorphism here? I ask because generally an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ is understood as an invertible entire function whose inverse is also entire. From your question it seems you are working with $\mathbb{C}$ as an additive group?

Comment: I'm working with $\mathbb C$ as if it were a commutative ring, so the automorphism would have to preserve the additive and the multiplicative structure.

Comment: The automorphism you proposed does not preserve the multiplicative structure of $\mathbb{C}$, meaning it does not satisfy $T(zw)=T(z)T(w)$. Perhaps you should first ask yourself what the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$ looks like.

Comment: Yes you are right I got it wrong, my function is not an automorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You can map 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_1+iy_1\\ x_2+iy_2\\ \vdots\\ x_n+iy_n\end{bmatrix}
\longmapsto \begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 &-y_1\\ y_1&x_1\end{bmatrix}
& 0 &0&\cdots & 0 \\
0&\begin{bmatrix} x_2 &-y_2\\ y_2&x_2\end{bmatrix}&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&\ddots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\begin{bmatrix} x_n &-y_n\\ y_n&x_n\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The automorphisms of $\mathbb C^n$ as an algebra consist only of the permutations. So we can represent each automorphism by an $n\times n$ permutation matrix represented as a $2n\times2n$ matrix where the $1$ are replaced with $I_2$ and the $0$ with $0_2$.

Comment: That's not exactly what he was asking. He was asking how to write an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a $2n\times 2n$ matrix (not how to write an element of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as one such matrix).

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Ok your answer is clear but how do I show that the only automorphisms are permutations?

Comment: The brute-force way: show first that a homomorphism  $\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C $ is necessarily projection to a coordinate (write it as linear, and then use multiplicativity); then use than an automorphism is one-to-one.

Comment: A more sophisticated way: note that  $\mathbb C^n=C (X) $, with $X $ having $n $ points. Automorphisms of $C (X) $ are given by the automorphisms of $X $ (as a discrete topological space).